# Qual finalidade do contentDescription?

Tags: android, warnings

Tenho na minha aplicação tenho vários *Warning*'s como consta abaixo:

> [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

#### Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei um pouco e encontrei que se trata das questões de [**Acessibilidade**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html), porém não conseguir compreender muito bem. Qual finalidade do `contentDescription`? E porque aparece como `warning`?

Comment: O SOen tem uma **[resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730673/missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-in-xml)** para sua pergunta. _Apenas complementando_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `contentDescription` é usado para [acessibilidade](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html), por exemplo com o recurso do *[Talkback](http://www.androidcentral.com/what-google-talk-back)*, caso o usuário tenha algum problema visual. Essa *label* pode ser usada para descrever o elemento. No caso o *warning* é para que sua aplicação seja mais acessível mesmo.

Caso seja um elemento seja estático, não mude, você pode colocar uma descrição. Essa descrição vai ser "lida" para o usuário que tem problemas de visão. Pode ser que ele tenha pouca visão, consiga enxergar o elemento na tela mas não consegue distinguir, caso haja essa descrição, o Talkback vai ler (usando áudio) para o usuário que vai ser capaz de entender o que está sendo exibido.

*Widgets* não textuais como `ImageViews` e `ImageButtons` devem usar o atributo `contentDescription` para especificar uma descrição textual do *widget* de tal modo que os leitores de tela e outras ferramentas de acessibilidade podem descrever adequadamente a interface do usuário.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que elemento "construído" na tela para o usuário eu devo colocar uma descrição? E na prática, como exatamente é usado, considerando que o usuário é cego, como mostra para ele que isso é uma imagem.?"

Comment: Se for um elemento que não muda, você pode colocar uma descrição. Essa descrição vai ser "lida" para o usuário que tem problemas de visão. Pode ser que ele tenha pouca visão, consiga enxergar o elemento na tela mas não consegue distinguir, caso haja essa descrição, o Talkback vai ler (usando áudio) para o usuário que vai ser capaz de entender o que está sendo exibido.

Comment: Melhorei a resposta mais um pouco. Obrigado!